# AJAX call PHP service login . Cordova

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I'm new at this and I'm having some trouble making a login.
This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'login.php', 
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'uname=TEST',
        dataType: 'json', 
        async: false,

        success: function (response){ 
            alert ("success"); 
            if (response.success) { 
                alert("you're logged in");
            }else {
                alert("Your login failed");
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
       }
    }); 

});
```

The problem is that it ALWAYS goes to the error callback, I have tried running the PHP file on its own and it works (if I hardcode a user name there).

I have no clue why it's always going on error, any help?

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'conection.php';

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$uname = $_POST['user'];

$sql = "SELECT IdUser FROM user WHERE IdUser = '$uname'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//echo $sql . " " . mysql_affected_rows();

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
    $response['success'] = true;
}else{
    $response['success'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct? What does the Network Monitor (in browser Developer Tools) shows you for this request?

Comment: And why the `crossDomain` option is set?

Comment: What does this have to do with Cordova?...

Comment: Don't you need to pass something in addition to user name to actually make a login (like a password)?

Comment: Since you are not inserting, updating, replacing or deleting anything with your query, mysql_affected_rows will return zero always.  But that's not why your error callback is firing.

Comment: Yes Mike, this is just to test if I can make it work, then I will make the rest once I get a simple example working.

And James, I made a test hardcoding the user name in the php file and affected rows returns 1. That is working fine, the problem is that somehow I cant get the user value in the PHP file I guess

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you pass to the AJAX call is 'uname', but the one you're looking for in the php is 'user' - change one of them to match the other.

Comment: actually that was my mystake when editing the code here in SO, in the real version that's ok

Answer (score 0):

Try updating as below:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'login.php', 
    //crossDomain: true,
    data: {"user":"TEST"}, // updated the uname to user which is @ php side
    dataType: 'json', 
    //async: false,
```

---

I think you can takeout the `crossDomain:true` and `async:false` from your ajax.